# WooCommerce: Add value to attribute editing product

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, attributes

I have a woocommerce attribute that is called 'arguments'. This attribute has a lot of value, and i set the attribute as a select value (dropdown menu for selection) instead of text.
Doing this, when i go to the product's editing page, i have a dropdown menu for add the value i want, but i can't create a new one. I need to have this menu, but i also need to have a text-field where i can put a new value if it isn't in the dropdown menu.

I asked to the woocommerce support too, but they can't help me.
I can code a plugin by myself, is not a big deal, but i didn't found how woocommerce manage the editing product page.

Thanks everyone in advance.
- Kryuko
Screenshot > https://i.stack.imgur.com/2udB1.jpg

Comment: So basically what you want is an input field with autocomplete feature?

Comment: No, i want this dropdown menu. But i also want a new input field to add a custom value if it isn't in the list.

Comment: If a text input with autocomplete is more easy do to, i would like to do that. But anyway i don't know how to do both things.